# Does @Input give a two way binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, input

The way I thought @Input worked would directly give a big "No!" to this question. However, today I stumbled upon some strange behavior, or maybe I always thought the wrong way about @Input..

I've made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjbtis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to show the issue. This happens in the stackblitz for Angular 7.0.1, but in my local project, it also happens on Angular 6.1.2.

The stackblitz shows a simple parent component that has an object. The object is passed to a child component via @Input. Both the child and parent component have a function that changes the object. They also both show the object's value in the template.

I expected to see that when the parent changes the object, it will change it in the child. However, I did not expect that when the child changes the object, it also changes it for the parent. The stackblitz does show this behavior, however. I always thought you would need to explicitly emit an event via @Output to make a flow to the parent and change it there from the child component.

Comment: A big "No?!" that slapped in my face too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is "no". In your example, the value that you pass to the `@Input` property is a reference to an object. If you had two-way binding, you could assign a new object to that property in the child component:

```
this.thing = { name: "world", nbm: 10 };
```

and the corresponding property in the parent component would be updated accordingly. That is not the case, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmkb6n).

However, since the parent and child components have a reference to the same object, they can both modify one of its properties, and that change will be observed in the other component.

---

In order to implement two-way binding, you can add an `@Output` property with the same name followed by `Change`, and emit the event when the change occurs:

```
@Input() thing: any;
@Output() thingChange = new EventEmitter();

setNewObject(){
  this.thing = { name: "world", nmb: 10 };
  this.thingChange.emit(this.thing);
}
```

The change will then be reflected to the parent component if the two-way binding syntax is used:

```
<child2 [(thing)]="thing"></child2>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elswfz) for a demo.

---

If you want to prevent the child component from modifying the original object, you should bind the object properties instead of the object itself:

```
@Input() thingName: string;
@Input() thingNmb: number;
```

```
<child [thingName]="thing.name" [thingNmb]="thing.nmb"></child>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly: What maybe confused me initially, is that the change detection is something different than the **actual** updating of the variables. If the reference is passed, and the instance is updated in the child component, this is actually directly edited in the parent component. Just the visual update is done after the change detection is fired.

Comment: In all these cases, the view is updated to reflect what actually happens in the data. The important point is the distinction between (1) updating a property of the `Input` object in the child component, and (2) modifying the value of the `Input` property by assiging a new object to it. The latter case does not propagate to the parent component with one-way binding.

Comment: hi @ConnorsFan  should programmers double bind a reference type anyway in Angular for good practice, or leave it as an input in the question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `Angular Change Detection` flows from `parent` to `child` however what you are experiencing is not related to `Object` `reference`. Since the shared object in `parent` and `child` point to the same `reference`, it will update in both the component.

Whenever you make any change through child component, shared object will be changed in the parent component as well and Angular will detect changes and trigger the UI update.

However that is not same case with primitive data type. What you have thought is true for primitive data type. In case primitive data type changes moves from Parent to child not vice versa.

Here is the demo for the same - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1wusrc

Comment: hi should programmers double bind a reference type anyway in Angular for good practice, or leave it as an input in the question?

Comment: Do not do double bind until and unless it required.It will impact the performance unnecessarily. You can keep as it is if it serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Two way data binding is the combination of both `event` binding and `property` binding **banana like syntax** - Where `[(ngModel)]` is the combination of `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` events

Here comes the magic with the word `Change` when a model name followed by the `Change` word angular will recognize that it will be two way data binding and makes it to work as like that

Coming to `Child` component `@Input()` is the kind off passing data to the child as `property` binding whereas `@Output()` is the kind off emitting data from the child to the parent as `event` binding - So to achieve two way binding you need both - check the example below

```
getModelList: any[];
    @Output() modelListChange: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
    @Input()
    get modelList(): any[] {
        return this.getModelList;
    }
    set modelList(value) {
        this.getModelList = value;
        this.modelListChange.emit(this.getModelList);
    }
```

In the above code we have `modelList` property and `modelListChange` property with the combination of both the bindings so we can access the `modelList` property as `[(modelList)]="value"` and that is your two way binding property

Accessing from parent - `<multi-dropdown [(modelList)]="value"></multi-dropdown>` now your parent property will be updated based on two way data binding - Make sure you spell the `Change` correctly which is case sensitive too

Hope this will help you - Thanks Happy coding !!

Comment: That does make sense to me. However, I do not understand why it behaves like this when I only put the @Input in the component, and thus it does not have the two way binding.

Comment: Same object reference will always makes the two way binding. Its not about the Angular but how the oops work.

Comment: But then you never have a one way binding for a non-primitive type (refering to @SunilSingh s comment)?

Comment: Because both the `@Input` and `@Output` have different binding style

Answer (score 1):

When change detection strategy is set to ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default, angular will often trigger change detections and yes, this will work.

Set it to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, and you will see different behavior.

This setting is configured in the Component annotation:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-awesome-component',
    templateUrl: './my-awesome-component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyAwesomeComponent{

}
```

**edit:** i just tried changing the ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush in your stackblitz, and the changes are still being reflected. I just read the docs again, and apparently the reason why this is always updated is because the click event on your button triggers change detection, and change detection is triggered from child to parent. So you could say that the change detection bubbles up to the root like an html event would.

Comment: This still makes little sense to me. If I add this detection strategy, changing the object in the parent changes in the parent, but not in the child. Changing the object in the child changes it in both components. This almost seems as if there is a binding upwards to the parent component, but no binding downwards via the Input. My expected result would be that when you change the variable in the parent component, it changes in the child (via Input), but the otherway around is only possible via Output. Clearly this does not seem to be the case?

Comment: I just edited the anwer, you are correct: change detection travels upward in the component tree, but not downward. And the initiator of the change detection is your click event.

Comment: hi Davy hi should programmers double bind a reference type anyway in Angular for good practice, or leave it as an input in the question?